# How to crop image using extended_image in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to edit the image using extended_image in flutter after taking the image but i am not able to do it. How to use the extended_image in flutter.

```
 final picker = ImagePicker();

Future getImage() async {
final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

setState(() {
  _image = File(pickedFile.path);
});


  _croppedImage =   ExtendedImage.file(
  _image,
  fit: BoxFit.contain,
  mode: ExtendedImageMode.editor,
  extendedImageEditorKey: editorKey,
  initEditorConfigHandler: (state) {
    return EditorConfig(
        maxScale: 8.0,
        cropRectPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        hitTestSize: 20.0,
        cropAspectRatio: CropAspectRatios.original);
  },
);

}
```

But it is not providing the editor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ExtendedImage.file in widget tree, not as function, example in author's github, [image_editor_demo](https://github.com/fluttercandies/extended_image/blob/master/example/lib/pages/image_editor_demo.dart)

Comment: Link Leading to 404